# algorithm for : how to separate sets with common range into each distinct range

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, range

i have tried this problem for quite some time but cannot find a good solution :

suppose we have ranges of integers like

```
 100 - 1000
 200 - 300
 500 - 600
 550 - 575
 800 - 1200
 1100 - 2300
```

so i want to get these intermixing ranges into each separate distinct range

```
 100 - 199
 200 - 300
 301 - 499
 500 - 549
 550 - 575
 575 - 600
 800 - 1099
 1100 - 1200
 1201 - 2300
```

is there some standard algorithm for this ?

thanks

Comment: Something along the line of a Radix sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort would be a start. You can then add in special cases for other parts.

Comment: Take a look at [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and [range trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shove every number into a single array, sort and dedupe. In C++, inserting them all into a `std::set<int>` has the desired effect. In Python, you can write `sorted(set(x for (a, b) in ranges for x in (a, b)))`.

In the resulting collection, adjacent pairs represent non-overlapping ranges.

It's important to note that this technique relies on the [a, b) convention (i.e., inclusive on the left; exclusive on the right) for describing ranges.